# Why can't Python find my path? (django)

Tags: python, django

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/svn-repos/myproject')
from myproject.settings import *
```

But, it says module not found when I run the script?
By the way, settings.py has been set up and manage.py syncdb works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `sys.path.append('/home/myuser/svn-repos')` instead. Then when you `import myproject`, it looks in `svn-repos` for the `myproject` folder, and looks in that for `settings`.

Alternatively, leave it as is and just `import settings`. This is less good because it's less specific and you may end up importing something other than what you intend.

You may also want to consider `sys.path.insert(0, 'yourpath')` because python starts at the beginning of that dict and works backwards, so whatever you put at the front takes precedence, solving the aforementioned `settings` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/svn-repos/myproject')
from settings import *
```

Note that

```
from settings import *
```

makes it difficult to track down where imported variables come from. It is not a good practive if you can avoid it.